# How to build-in MS Outlook voting buttons into SSRS generated email

Tags: email, reporting-services, outlook

I want to create a pdf offer letter for our customers using an SSRS report subscription. The report creates the pdf file and mails it out to the desired address on a schedule. So far so good.

However, I want to build in the MS Outlook Voting buttons. So if the customer wants to accept the offer, he clicks the voting button "Accept", otherwise he clicks the voting button "Reject". Obviously, he can only use those buttons when he has MS Outlook.

How can I tell SSRS to not only send the email but also build in the voting button function?

Comment: You won't be able to do this in SSRS. I'd build a VSTO Outlook Addin in C# or VB.NET to create the email, attach the SSRS report as pdf and then add the voting buttons.

Comment: @aduguid: Thank you! We will implement a power shell command to get this done. I was just hoping that i could everything done in one place (SSRS).